# Return result of an mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, levenshtein-distance

I have installed [this Levenshtein function](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/610-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql) in MYSQL. The maker advises to use this:

```
select levenshtein('butt', 'but') from test;
select levenshtein_ratio('butt', 'but') from test;
```

I want to calculate the Levenshtein Ratio between $search and each "name" entry in the DB and then echo it in PHP.

How can I accomplish that? Thanks in advance

```
$search = "Paul"; // The string I want compared to each DB entry

$query = "SELECT name, ??? FROM names"; // What's the MYSQL I need to use?

$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

  echo "Levenshtein Ratio: ".$row['???'];
  echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: If I use `$query = "SELECT levenshtein('butt', 'but') FROM names;` and `$row['levenshtein']`, I get "Notice: Undefined index: levenshtein in..."

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an alias the function return

```
SELECT levenshtein('butt', 'but') as levenshtein FROM
```

then it can be accessed from the `levenshtein` index.

```
$row['levenshtein']
```

Also note:

> In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, the mysqli_fetch_array() function can also store the data in associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys.

So if you didn't want the alias you could do:

```
$row[1]
```

this is less readable/maintainable to me though.

When in doubt about what an array contains you can check it with `print_r` or `var_dump`. Those will give you the indices and the values the array has.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
<?php 

$search = "Paul"; // The string I want compared to each DB entry
$query = "SELECT name, levenshtein(name, '".mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $search)."') AS result FROM names";

$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  echo "Levenshtein Ratio for ".$row['name'].' : '.$row['result']."<br />";

}
```